# mgo error when unmarshal map[string]interface{}

Tags: json, mongodb, go, struct, mgo

I want to store an arbitrary json object in a struct:

```
type C struct {
  Name string `json:"name" bson:"name"`
  Config map[string]interface{} `json:"config" bson:"config"`
}
```

This works fine when I store any deeply nested json object, but when I go retrieve it and mgo tries to Unmarshal it, I get:

> Unmarshal can't deal with struct values. Use a pointer.

I'm not sure what's supposed to be a pointer. I get the same errors if I change it to:

```
Config *map[string]interface{}
```

The error occurs here: https://github.com/MG-RAST/golib/blob/master/mgo/bson/bson.go#L493

I don't know what it's reflecting on though.

Comment: Show us your code how you try to store and retrieve data. Aim for a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you are unmarshaling the input argument takes a pointer to the struct, and you need to define a type in order to use a pointer to a struct.

```
type myMap map[string]interface{}
```

Then you can make a pointer to that type notice the ampersand to indicate pointer to your struct for type myMap, with json you could do something like so:

```
json := []Byte{`{"name": "value"}`}
c := &myMap{"value": "name"}
json.Unmarshal(c, json)
```

So you need *myMap to the struct not a pointer to the type. In order to explain the specific solution to this problem you need to add the context of how mongodb is unmarshaling your json.

Comment: Yep, stupid error, I was passing the struct to One() - https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Query.One - and not a pointer to it.